# node.js - basic example of sync/async function interpolation

Tags: node.js, async-await, blocking, nonblocking

Sorry for the question but Im pretty new about the Blocking vs Non-Blocking concept..

I have a function "start()" that contains two functions (something_X) that contains a function (anything_x).

The functions "anything_X" are async.

```
var foo = ""
var bar = ""

start();
final();

//###########################

function start() {
  something_1();
  something_2();
}

function something_1() {
   anything_A(params, function(err, data){ foo = "hello" });
}

function something_2() {
    anything_B(params, function(err, data){ bar = "world" });
}

fucntion final() {
  console.log(foo + " " + bar);
}
```

How can I wait the two functions "something_X" before the execution of the function "final()"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using two approaches

```
var foo = ""
var bar = ""
```

1 - Promise;

```
start()
    .then(() => final())
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

2 - Async and Await

```
async function main() {
    await start();
    final();
}

//###########################
function start() {
    return Promise.all([something_1(), something_2()]);
}

function something_1() {
    anything_A(params, function (err, data) { foo = "hello" });
}

function something_2() {
    anything_B(params, function (err, data) { bar = "world" });
}

function final() {
    console.log(foo + " " + bar);
}
```